# What should happen to comments that suggested changes to a post after the post was edited to reflect those changes?

Tags: discussion, comments

A little while ago, I ran across this comment:

> This should have the meta tag, shouldn't it?

The [meta](/questions/tagged/meta) tag later got added to the post, and the comment is still there. I'm wondering, what should I do to this type of comment? I can think of three good options:

- Upvote the comment because it used to be useful
- Flag the comment as no longer needed because the post was already edited
- Leave the comment as it is

All of these seem like fine options to me. Which of them is the best one?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Flag em as no longer needed. Mods ought to be able to deal with it.